# Printing a different value in a text box on multiple copies

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a **button** that prints a form on the current record.

The form contains a combobox with something like: *123005TEST*
This combobox is a lookup to another textbox which is a combination of three text boxes(on a different form):

```
=([OrderNr] & (""+[Aantal]) & "" & [SapArtNr])
```

**OrderNr** is *12300* and **Aantal** is *5* and **SapArtNr** is *TEST*, creating: *123005TEST*

---

My question is, when I click print, is it possible to print a certain amount of copies based on **Aantal** *5*, so printing 5 copies.

And here comes the tricky part.

To have each printed copy a different value in the combobox, so the first copy would have this written in the combobox on the printed paper: *123001TEST* and copy two would be *123002TEST* and so on, until 5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't understand which textbox will receive the sequential text. So I put a dummy in the example code:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub cmdPrintIt_Click()
    Dim strOrderNr As String
    Dim strAantal As String
    Dim strSapArtNr As String
    Dim intHowManyCopies As Integer
    Dim intCopy As Integer
    Dim strToTextBox As String

    strOrderNr = Me.OrderNr.Text
    strAantal = Me.Aantal.Text
    strSapArtNr = Me.SapArtNr.Text

    On Error Resume Next
    intHowManyCopies = CInt(strAantal)
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    If intHowManyCopies <> 0 Then
        For intCopy = 1 To intHowManyCopies
            strToTextBox = strOrderNr & CStr(intCopy) & strSapArtNr
            Me.TheTextBoxToReceiveText.Text = strToTextBox
            'put your code to print here
        Next
Else
    MsgBox "Nothing to print! Check it."
End If
End Sub
```